# Jquery Tooltip for a particular column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In a datatable, the tooltip has to be added to the only first column rows while the mouse hovers it,

> 

Rendering |  engine    |Browser |Platform(s)Engine | version | CSS grade
Gecko     |Firefox 1.0 |Win 98+ | OSX.2+           | 1.7     |    A
Gecko     |Firefox 1.5 |Win 98+ | OSX.2+           | 1.8     |   A

```
 $('#datatable').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  info: false,
  dom: 'Bfrtip'
});
$('.data-tooltip').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').addClass('tooltip');
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Developers are not here to code for you. We are here to help people solve their own problems. So please, try to code it yourself and if you cannot then post your attempt. If not, is probable the post will be deleted or you wont get help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script> $(document).ready(function () { 
$.each(datatable.data, function (i, item){ 
item.tooltip = item.name;
 })
 }); 
table = $('#example').DataTable({
 columns: columns, 
dom: "tp", 
data: datatable.data, 
createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) { 
$("td:first", row).attr("title", data.tooltip); 
} 
});
 var datatable={ "data": [ 
{ "name": "lion", "position": "System Architect" },
{ "name": "tiger", "position": "Accountant" } 
]};
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).